# How to add Category while adding product in Django form? Just like the Django admin form

Tags: django, django-forms, django-admin

So I am trying to build an inventory system.
I have 2 models, Categories and Product connected through the ManyToMany field.
I want to add a category while I am adding the product just like it happens in the Django admin form.
How can I do that?

**My model.py File**

```
class Categories(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
organisation = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

def __str__(self):
    return f"{self.name}"


class Product(models.Model):
    category = models.ManyToManyField(Categories)
    brand = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    model = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    hac = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)
    rate = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
    stock = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    # organisation = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    date_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.brand} {self.model} "
```

**My form.py file**

```
class ProductModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Product
    fields = '__all__'
```

**My code output **
[image]

**See the below screenshots to understand what I want to do. I basically want that plus button option to add a category from the product form itself.**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should show snippets of codes that we need to provide an answer.

Comment: sorry for inconvenience. Please have a look at it now

Comment: @sikanderkhan I see that you have yout "Product" model as a modelform in forms.py file. Have you tried adding "Category" model in forms.py file too? that might work